# Reading from a text file of unknown size without malloc

Tags: c++, arrays, file, visual-c++

I'm a student new to c++, so if this is a silly question, I apologize. I am trying to read from a file with a known number of columns but an unknown number of rows and place the values into an array of matching size. The program must be flexible and work with any number of rows in a given file. I attempted to do this by calling a function to find the number of rows in the file, returning that value, then setting that value equal to a constant, when I ran into a problem: c++ does not allow you set a constant equal to a variable. For instance:

```
int const SIZE = 20;
double array[SIZE];
```

Correctly initializes "array," but

```
int const SIZE = function();
double array[SIZE];
```

Does not work and gives the error "expression must have a constant value". Now, my problem is someone else asked this exact question, but the answer he was given was to use `malloc`, but our class hasn't learned how to use that yet. Is there a decently clean way to initialize an array with the data from a file of unknown size using only while and for loops (since that's all we've learned so far)?

Comment: Use `std::vector` instead. It grows automatically as needed.

Comment: This is C++, not Sparta! `malloc` should be the last resort of a fairly long list.

Comment: you don't like `malloc` you can use `new`. :)

Comment: `std::vector<double> array(SIZE);` *will* work. (Even though `array` might not  be the best name for the object).